# How to read write file in data/data with root

Tags: android, root

Now I'm using `File` to check some files or delete them **with root**. Here is code:

```
String tempName = null;
    boolean hasFound = false;
    File baseDir = new File("data/data/" + pkgName + "/databases");
    if (!baseDir.exists() || !baseDir.isDirectory()) {
        listener.onExecuteFiled();
    } else {
        File[] filelist = baseDir.listFiles();
        for (File file : filelist) {
            if (!file.isDirectory()) {
                tempName = file.getName();
                if (tempName.toLowerCase().contains("wegamedb")) {
                    if (!file.delete()) {
                        listener.onExecuteFiled();
                        return;
                    } else {
                        hasFound = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (hasFound) {
            listener.onExecuteSuccess();
        } else {
            listener.onExecuteFiled();
        }
    }
```

But `baseDir.listFiles();` return null, so I want to know how to get root permission to run those code ? I can run shell with `su` but do not know how to do the same thing to `File`.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

you missed a `/` from

```
File baseDir = new File("data/data/" + pkgName + "/databases");
```

it should be

```
File baseDir = new File("/data/data/" + pkgName + "/databases");
```

if you have a context I would use `getDatabasePath` ([Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)) the documentation), which returns the absolute path of the database.

```
File file = context.getDatabasePath("DATABASE_NAME");
```

and if you want to list all the files into `databases`

```
File parentFile = context.getDatabasePath("DATABASE_NAME").getParent();
if (parentFile != null) { 
     File[] dbs = parentFile.listFiles();
}
```

Comment: Thanks ,I'm deleting other packages' file in /data/data, so I can't use context to do this. And after I add the `/` it also returns null.

Comment: who is returning null? listFiles() ?

Comment: yes, I have solved it , I run chmod 777 shell for those dir and files, and now the listFiles() won't return null.

Comment: are you running it only for your app? If it is the case you don't need to change the permissions